# Exporting non-S3-methods with dots in the name using roxygen2 v4

Tags: r, roxygen2

Since `roxygen2` version `4.0.0`, the `@S3method` tag has been deprecated in favour of using `@export`.

The package now tries to detect if a function is an S3 method, and automatically adds the line `S3method(function,class)` to the `NAMESPACE` file if it think it is one.

The problem is that if a function is not an S3 method but its name contains a `.` then roxygen sometimes makes a mistake and adds the line when it shouldn't.

Is there a way to tell roxygen that a function is not an S3 method?

---

As requested, here's a reproducible example.

I have a package that imports `R.oo`, with a function named `check.arg`.

```
library(roxygen2)
package.skeleton("test")
cat("Imports: R.oo\n", file = "test/DESCRIPTION", append = TRUE)
writeLines(
  "#' Check an argument 
#' 
#' Checks an argument.
#' @param ... Some arguments.
#' @return A value.
#' @export
check.arg <- function(...) 0",
  "test/R/check.arg.R"
)
roxygenise("test")
```

Now the namespace contains the line `S3method(check,arg)`.

`check` is an S3 generic in `R.oo`, so roxygen is trying to be smart and guessing that I want `check.arg` to be an S3 method.  Unfortunately, these functions are unrelated, so I don't.

(To preempt suggestions that I just rename `check.arg`: this is legacy code written by others, and I've created a `checkArg` replacement, but I need to leave `check.arg` as a deprecated function for compatibility.)

Comment: I believe you just use `@export` with the full name of the function. It would be helpful to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to test.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the solution, and thanks for reminding me not to be lazy.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As Mr Flick commented, appending the full function name to the roxygen line works correctly. If I change the line to:

```
#' @export check.arg
```

then the `NAMESPACE` file contains:

```
export(check.arg)
```

Comment: The other problem to take care of is the usage statement, which will say `## S3 method for class ’check’\n check(...)` unless you fix it.  One way is to just add a `##' @usage check.arg(x)` directive, not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: **Note that** the above solution will get you a correct entry in your `NAMESPACE` file.  However, to get the function *documented* correctly, you also need to add a `@usage` tag, otherwise the message `## S3 method for class 'arg'` will appear just above the signature of your function in it's `.Rd` file and the signature in the help file will be `check(...)` and not `check.arg(...)`.

Comment: @Jthorpe Great note (would be worth an answer!). `R CMD check` may still complain with a warning like *Found the following apparent S3 methods exported but not registered:* and you have to rename the function then to for a successful submission at CRAN (they don't allow warnings).

Answer (score -1):

Use `@method generic class` and `@export` instead of `@S3method`. Take a look at this thread:
[S3 method help (roxygen2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361616/s3-method-help-roxygen2)

Comment: This question isn't about how to document S3 methods; it is about the opposite problem of documenting things that aren't S3 methods (but roxygen thinks that they are).