# Why does a R method prefixed with "train." get converted into an s3method when building in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-caret, roxygen2

I used RStudio's "Build and Reload" feature to build a new function:

```
#' minimal example
#' @param param1 First param
#' @export
#' @examples
#' train.caret.model.list()
#' 
train.hello.world <- function(){
  return ("hello world")
}
```

I looked in my NAMESPACE file where I expected to find the following generated:

```
export(train.hello.world)
```

But when I checked the NAMESPACE file, what was actually generated was:

```
S3method(train,hello.world)
```

It looks like there's something special in starting a function name with "`train.`"

It might have something to do with my package including `caret` as a dependency, as you can see in this line from my description file:

```
Depends: fmri, oro.nifti, doMC, caret
```

I am writing a wrapper function for `caret`'s `train` function. I can imagine this feature could be quite helpful to know, but I couldn't find any reference to this behavior online.

I'm also using `roxygen2` for documentation, but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: I think roxygen is very relevant and your answer lies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594507/exporting-non-s3-methods-with-dots-in-the-name-using-roxygen2-v4