# R CMD Check non-S3-methods with dots in the name where part of name before dot coincides with a generic in utils

Tags: r-package, cran, roxygen2, r-s3

This question is related to but distinct from [Exporting non-S3-methods with dots in the name using roxygen2 v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594507/exporting-non-s3-methods-with-dots-in-the-name-using-roxygen2-v4).  From that post I learned that one needs to use `@export function.name` in order for the NAMESPACE to be written correctly by roxygen.  I have done that and the NAMESPACE is correctly written.

My problem comes when I do R CMD Check.  I have legacy code that has a function `tail.g()`.  R CMD Check throws a NOTE noting that an apparent S3 method has been exported but not registered.

A reproducible example is below.  Observe that `xxxx.g` doesn't have the NOTE, which leads me to believe that because `tail` is a generic in the utils package I need some special work-around.  I'd prefer not to rename tail.g to tail_g because this is legacy code.  I wish to eliminate all notes for a successful CRAN submission.

```
library(roxygen2)
package.skeleton("test")
writeLines(
  "#' Check an argument 
  #' 
  #' Checks an argument.
  #' @param ... Some arguments.
  #' @return A value.
  #' @export tail.g
  tail.g <- function(...) 0",
  "test/R/tail.g.R"
)
writeLines(
  "#' Check an argument 
  #' 
  #' Checks an argument.
  #' @param ... Some arguments.
  #' @return A value.
  #' @export xxxx.g
  xxxx.g <- function(...) 0",
  "test/R/xxxx.g.R"
)
roxygenise("test")
setwd("./test")
devtools::check(document=FALSE)
```

Gives the NOTE:

```
checking S3 generic/method consistency ... NOTE
Found the following apparent S3 methods exported but not registered:
  tail.g
```

How do I eliminate the NOTE for tail.g() without renaming?

Answer (score 1):

This is a dirty hack, but it works: **just register the functions as methods, *in addition to* the export**.

So your `NAMESPACE` could have two lines like this:

```
export(tail.g)
S3method(tail, g)
```

This appears to be enough to eliminate the warning and get a clean CRAN submission. The only negative side effect I can think of for regular users is a few bogus entries in the output of things like `methods(class="g")` or `methods("tail")`. Most regular users shouldn't even notice.

With roxygen2, you can use the `@rawNamespace` tag to include the required `S3method` directive in your `NAMESPACE` file:

```
writeLines(
  "#' Check an argument 
  #' 
  #' Checks an argument.
  #' @param ... Some arguments.
  #' @return A value.
  #' @export tail.g
  #' @rawNamespace S3method(tail, g)
  tail.g <- function(...) 0",
  "test/R/tail.g.R"
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it will still throw an error if the signatures are incompatible, e.g. if your function is `tail.g(foo, bar)` and the existing method is `tail(x, ...)`.