# Why does Roxygen recognize some functions and S3Methods and rename some functions in NAMESPACE?

Tags: r, namespaces, package, roxygen2

I am taking over an R project and I am attempting to keep the naming as consistent as possible from the person who worked on the project before me.

I have created several functions for a package being developed. Above each function, I have the `#' @export` which is used to create the `NAMESPACE` file in `roxygen2`:

```
#' @export
a.function = function(x){
# do stuff
}

#' @export
another.function = function(x){
# do stuff
}
```

When I create the documentation using `roxygen2`, the `NAMESPACE` file created will categorize some functions as methods. Periods (`.`) will also be converted into commas (`,`). For example, the namespace for the functions above might appear as

```
S3method(a.function)
export(another.function)
```

Furthermore, the person who worked on the project before me occasionally used 3 periods when naming a function:

```
yet.another.function = function(x){
# do stuff
}
```

But `Roxygen2` converts the first period into a comma in all functions with 3 periods in the `NAMESPACE` file. By this I mean that the function above would appear as

```
export(yet,another.function)
```

in the `NAMESPACE` file.

My questions are as follows:

- How does `Roxygen` distinguish some functions as `S3method` and some as functions and use `export` in `NAMESPACE`?
- Is it possible to force or coerce `Roxygen` to recognize all functions as functions and to use `export`?
- Is it possible to stop `Roxygen` from converting periods in the function name to commas in the `NAMESPACE` file?

Unfortunately I was not able to directly find the answer to these in either the `Roxygen` documentation or other posts on stack Overflow.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/673 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594507/exporting-non-s3-methods-with-dots-in-the-name-using-roxygen2-v4